# Wrap ach group of elements with class starting with same characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-traversing

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7hABQ/12/) is a fiddle of what I have so far.
I want to wrap all groups of 'OK' starting classes into their own:

```
<div class="wrapper">
```

I figured one possibility could be to take the first element of each group, then run a `nextUntil()` until it finds element with class not matching the class, then `.wrapAll()`.

It should in the en look like this:

```html
<div class="foo">aaa</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ok-4">bbb</div>
  <div class="ok-21887">ccc</div>
  <div class="ok-6">ddd</div>
</div>
<div class="bar">eee</div>
<div class="baz">fff</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ok-5a4">ggg</div>
  <div class="ok-12">hhh</div>
</div>
<div class="bim">iii</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To wrap every individual div you can use `.wrap()`:

```
$('div[class^="ok"]').wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hABQ/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div[class^="ok"]').wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hABQ/13/)**

Comment: Felix, you can now see intended result